# How to make boolean expressions shorter ? or or or or or

Tags: python, boolean-expression

```
var = raw_input()

if "0" in var or "1" in var or "2" in var or "3" in var or "4" in var or "5" in var or "6" in var or "7" in var or "8" in var or "9" in var:
    print "yay"
else:
    print: ":("
```

Is there a way to make it shorter by me not having to write all the numbers ? It's ok if it's (0,10), what if it's (0, 10000)

Is it possbile to use lists here somehow ?

Comment: You'll probably get more useful answers if you were to tell us what you're trying to achieve by checking the 10,000 hard-coded substrings.

Comment: Are you sure that you don't mean `if var == "0" or var == "1"` etc? Do you really mean "Is there a digit anywhere in var?"?

Comment: @JohnMachin Yes, I mean "Is there a digit anythere in var"

Comment: @aix Well I'm writing a simple program to calculate the 3rd angle of triangle if two are given.I want to make sure there is a digit in a string then convert it to integer.Also I need to make sure there aren't other simbols but numbers in the string

Comment: Your question is a clear example of [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/177799) :)

Comment: @RikPoggi Thanks for letting me know about it.I will form better questions in the future :) Still boolean expressions is a often used thing and sooner or later I would have come to the point when it's the best option also.

Comment: @Tomas: The code you posted didn't even do what you now confess you really wanted to do. Concentrate on getting your code correct before getting it short. Also try get your story sorted out before you post -- "I need to make sure there aren't other symbols but numbers in the string" was a very late addition and contradicted your response to my question only a little earlier.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
any(str(i) in var for i in range(10))
```

Comment: Considering the question, the answer is rather ``print 'yay' if any(dig in var for dig in '0123456789') else ':('`` . However, I upvote

Comment: I think my solution is more generic, for instance if you want to check for more numbers. I also believe that if it just want to check numbers inside a string the re solution is better.

Comment: @shenshei: It would be nonsense to use your code with `n > 10`: there are only 10 digits.

Comment: @RikPoggi: I guess shenshei has a more general use case in mind.

Comment: @RikPoggi: Yep with range(n) with n>10 it is stupid, but you could other ranges. Anyway I think the regex manner is more concise and efficient for the case of finding numbers in a string.

Comment: @shenshei I said: "considering the question". Besides that, if your understated idea was the possibility to extend to greater numbers, it is a bad idea because, supposing **'23'** is in _var_, then **str(2)** would be detected present in **var** before **str(23)** could be detected.

Answer (score 5):

Regular expressions are quite concise in that case:

```
import re
if re.search(r"\d", str):
  print "yay"
else
  print ":("
```

Or even shorter:

```
print "yay" if re.search(r"\d", str) else ":("
```

Comment: Just a suggestion. Don't [overuse](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/06/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems.html) Regex. :)

Comment: @AbhijeetRastogi: There are actually three reasons to choose regular expressions here: 1. The language to match is regular 2. It's more concise than the other methods and very clear what the purpose is 3. It's less complex runtime-wise than the other methods (`O(n)` instead of `O(n*m)`). If you gave me at least one reason NOT to use regular expressions here, I might actually think about your suggestion (hint: The argument laid out in the linked article does not apply here because of 1. ;) Otherwise you are nothing but a troll.

Comment: @Niklas Baumstark One reason: a solution with regex isn't the fastest one, even if the regex is compiled before being used and timed. See my answer

Comment: @Niklas Baumstark Well, I really loves regexes. But when unneeded, I don't insist to use them. The advantage of the **any()** function and the use of **in** to search in a string is that there is no need to import something (re module) and to spend time defining a compiled regex or compiling it at the moment of the search. If, in my code, I put the instruction ``regx = re.compile('\d')`` inside the timing loop, the time is even longer than with ``re.search('\d',var)`` : 0.0216940979929 (compared to 0.0178648403638 with ``re.search('\d',var)`` )

Comment: @Niklas Baumstarck I don't see how any other solution could be simpler than ``any(dig in var for dig in '0123456789')`` , module **re** having formerly already been imported or not. If you think that the presence of the word _search_ in the solution with regex is fine to understand instantly what is the purpose of the instruction, one can also write ``any(digit_present in var for digit_present in '0123456789')``

Comment: @Niklas Baumstark Why do you say that performance difference is negligible : the fastest regex solution is 2 times slower than the  solution with **any()**

Comment: @eyquem: Sorry, I meant performance itself is negligible for that use case. That means, *unless it has been proved by profiling that this code presents a bottleneck in the application*, which I highly doubt from OP's description of the problem. If it indeed IS a bottleneck, we probably also shouldn't use `any`, because it's not `O(n)` and an even faster solution exists (using native C code with lookup tables).

Comment: @Niklas Baumstark In my opinion, ``any(dig in var for dig in '0123456789')`` is a simple expression and the fastest solution. I don't understand your obstination to dispute about the interest of it. Your considerations are constantly changing and I don't find this debate crucial.

Comment: @Niklas Baumstarck By the way, evoking a native C code is weird , and your solution using **ord()** and **chr()** is a complication of the following solution ``any(47<ord(c)<58 for c in var)`` that executes in 0.274922371419 seconds, while your full complicated solution executes in 0.560456985455 seconds. - Personally, I stop this unfruitful debate at this point

Answer (score 4):

> I want to make sure there is a digit in a string then convert it to integer.Also I need to make sure there aren't other simbols but numbers in the string

To do this, you could apply `int()` to the string that you've read, catching `ValueError` exceptions:

```
def read_int(prompt):
    while True:
        var = raw_input(prompt)
        try:
            val = int(var)
            if val > 0: return val
            print 'the number must be positive, try again'
        except ValueError as ex:
            print 'invalid number, try again'

print read_int('enter a positive integer: ')
```

Answer (score 2):

The best answer is certainly

```
print 'yay' if any(c in '0123456789' for c in var) else ':('
```

anybody will easily understand why

### edit 1

No, it isn't the best answer, because it is the slowest one among the following methods.
I love regexes but I could'nt imagine that a solution using a regex would be the fastest one.
Even the use of set() is faster.

```
var = '''For all his fame and celebration, William Shakespeare remains a mysterious figure
with regards to personal history. There are just two primary sources for information
on the Bard: his works, and various legal and church documents that have survived from
Elizabethan times. Naturally, there are many gaps in this body of information, which
tells us little about Shakespeare the man. 
William Shakespeare was born in Stratford-upon-Avon, allegedly on April 23, 1564.'''

from time import clock
import re


n = 1000


te = clock()
for i in xrange(n):
    b = any(c in ('0123456789') for c in var)
print clock()-te


ss = set('0123456789')
te = clock()
for i in xrange(n):
    b = ss.intersection(var)
print clock()-te


te = clock()
for i in xrange(n):
    b = re.search('\d',var)
print clock()-te


regx = re.compile('\d')
te = clock()
for i in xrange(n):
    b = regx.search(var)
print clock()-te
```

result

```
0.157774521622
0.0335822010898
0.0178648403638
0.00936152499829
```

### edit 2

By Jove !
**shensei**'s answer IS the best answer, in fact.
Just the contrary of what I imagined !

```
from time import clock
import re


n = 1000

te = clock()
for i in xrange(n):
    b = any(dig in var for dig in '0123456789')
print clock()-te
```

result

```
0.00467852757823
```

I conclude that the exploration of **var** by `for dig in var` is really super-hyper-fast.
I only knew that it was very fast.

### edit 3

Nobody pointed out that the execution's time of the shensei's solution depends from the content of the analyzed string:

```
from time import clock
n = 1000

var = '''For all his fame and celebration, William Shakespeare remains a mysterious figure
with regards to personal history. There are just two primary sources for information
on the Bard: his works, and various legal and church documents that have survived from
Elizabethan times. Naturally, there are many gaps in this body of information, which
tells us little about Shakespeare the man. 
William Shakespeare was born in Stratford-upon-Avon, allegedly on April 00, 0000.'''

te = clock()
for i in xrange(n):
    b = any(dig in var for dig in '0123456789')
print clock()-te 

var = '''For all his fame and celebration, William Shakespeare remains a mysterious figure
with regards to personal history. There are just two primary sources for information
on the Bard: his works, and various legal and church documents that have survived from
Elizabethan times. Naturally, there are many gaps in this body of information, which
tells us little about Shakespeare the man. 
William Shakespeare was born in Stratford-upon-Avon, allegedly on April 99, 9999.'''

te = clock()
for i in xrange(n):
    b = any(dig in var for dig in '0123456789')
print clock()-te
```

gives results

```
0.0035278226702
0.0132472143806
```

Use of ompiled regex, that takes 0.00936152499829 seconds seems faster than shensei's solution in the worst case. But in fact , if the time of compiling the regex is included in the time measurement, the real execution's time is 0.0216940979929 seconds.
Then shensei's solution remains the fastest method.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the size of 'var' and the number of values you might be better off using sets.

```
values = set(map(str, range(10000)))
print(not set(var).isdisjoint(values))
```

10000 values doesn't make sense if `var = raw_input()`, but I guess you have another use case in mind.

Comment: ``map(str, range(10000))`` creates a list from which **set()** must then create a set. It is better to create the set instantly: ``set(str(i) for i in xrange(1000))`` . By the way, **range(10000)** is also a created list. Moreover, putting stringified numbers >9 in the set has no sense because if such a number is in the set, it is enough to detect its digits in the intersection to know that there is a number in var

Comment: In Python 3.x, neither range nor map create a list. I explicitly stated that 10000 values don't make sense, and that I assume Tomas has another use case in mind.

Comment: You're right: in Python 3, your use of functional manner is better than my generator expression required in Python 2

Answer (score 0):

```
var = raw_input()
list_of_strings = map(str, range(10))
if var in list_of_strings:
    print 'yay!'
else:
    print ':('
```

Or, cast `raw_input` to a string:

```
try:
    var = int(raw_input())
except ValueError as e:
    var = int(raw_input('Please enter a number!'))
if var in range(10):
    print 'yay'
else:
    print ':('
```

A note: my first example takes an extra step to convert the list of numbers into a list of strings. My second example goes the opposite way, and converts the input from a string to a number.

Answer (score 0):

From the O.P. comment: """I want to make sure there is a digit in a string then convert it to integer.Also I need to make sure there aren't other simbols but numbers in the string –"""

This is trivial in Python: 
  just do "`var.isdigit()`"  - .isdigit is a string method.

The recomended way to extract numbers from strings, though is:

```
try:
    result = int(var)
except ValueError:
    # put error handler code here
```